Expo Typescript connect to MQTT Broker
I'm trying to connect to MQTT broker. I uses mqtt and here is my code:
// the MQTT_URL is just a sample structure
const MQTT_URL = 'mqtt://sample-mqtt.com.ph';
const MQTT_OPTIONS = {
    clientId: 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8),
    clean: true
}

export const onMqttConnect = () => {
    const client = mqttConnect(MQTT_URL, MQTT_OPTIONS);

    client.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('Connected to MQTT broker');

        client.subscribe('test/topic', (err) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('Subscribed to topic');
                client.publish('test/topic', 'Hello MQTT');
            }
        });
    })

    client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
        console.log(`Received message from ${topic}: ${message.toString()}`);
    });

    client.on('error', (error) => {
        console.log(`MQTT error: ${error}`);
    });

    client.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Connection to MQTT broker closed');
    });

    return () => {
        client.end();
    }
}

I call it inside useEffect and it return Connection to MQTT broker closed. However if I run it as single file of code like node mqtt.js it return Connected to MQTT broker.
I also try to use react-native-mqtt and it return an error stating [TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object], and paho-mqtt similar with above it return Connection to MQTT broker closed.
Thank you for the help!

I managed to make it work using "react-native-paho-mqtt": "^0.1.1",

@Thomasino73 does it work with mqtt protocol? I think it only work with Web Socket.

I use it with mqtts

@Thomasino73 may I know how you declare your Client? Here is how I declare host const url = 'wss://sample-mqtt.com.ph:8883/mqtt', and on my Client is const client = new Client (url, 'clientId'), and I receive an error message, AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.

I have declared my client like so:
  import MQTT from "sp-react-native-mqtt";

  ...

  const mqttClient = await MQTT.createClient({
        clientId: "id_" + parseInt(id.toString()),
        uri: "mqtt://something.something:1883",
        host: "something.something",
        port: 1883,
        protocol: "mqtts",
        tls: false,
        keepalive: 60,
        protocolLevel: 0,
        clean: true,
        auth: true,
        user: "user",
        pass: "pass",
        automaticReconnect: true,
      });


Enabled the WebSocket support on my MQTT protocol, and declare host as ws://sample-mqtt.com.ph:port/mqtt.
